# Change target directory and storing result in a list

Tags: filenames

How can I make a function that matches a target directory at point, changing the user name to another one?

Example, with cursor on  `/home/peter/web/ergomax.org`  I want to change from `peter` to `paul`, then store the result in a list that I can access later on.

Comment: In what sort of buffer?  Dired?  If not, how will the filenames be formatted, and how robust does the detection need to be?  (filenames can contain all kinds of special characters, including spaces and even newlines potentially).

Comment: Yes, in dired would do.  Files would not contain spaces or other weird things.  The problematic task is how to add to a list that I can display.  Another difficulty is where I will put the information.  Might require another function to print or insert the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defvar my-list-for-later-access '())

(defun mash-homedir (username)
  "Substitute USERNAME into the pathname at point."
  (interactive "MUsername: ")
  (add-to-list
   'my-list-for-later-access
   (s-replace-regexp
    "/home/[^/]+/"
    (format "/home/%s/" username)
    (thing-at-point 'filename :no-properties))))
```

Comment: How can I view the list as I go along with the changes?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly: just enter `my-list-for-later-access RET` in the minibuffer using `M-x eval-expression RET` (`M-:`)